# can we provide WWWROOT folder like structure in views to download files in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, wwwroot

We have an application in asp.net core where numerous files will be generated and saved to wwwroot folder,We want to provide folder structure similar to wwwroot folder to download multiple files.Please do suggest if it is  possible and any others ways to do it. My requirement is when I run my application it will generate excel,json,text files in a folder with name output files in wwwroot itself,so i have to provide these files for the user to download.So i want to know if  is it possible to provide files with same structure as my output files folder in wwwroot to show in front end using any other technology.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do in more detail? You can put files in folders under wwwroot to keep them organised

Comment: No sure what is your requirement.If you want to serve files outside the web root,refer to:[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-outside-of-web-root).

Comment: Hi thanks for your  response,My requirement is when I run my application it will generate excel,json,text files in a folder with name output files in wwwroot itself,so i have provide these files for the user to download.So i want to is it possible like providing files with same structure as my output files folder in front end using any other technology.